# php javascript working to show one value in textbox but cant get the multiple

Tags: php, javascript, sql

i have this code below of javascript:

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/get_user.php?q="+str,true);


xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

and the php sql script is given below:

```
<?php
     $testQrys = "SELECT * FROM test where status = 1";
     $testdbResults = mysql_query($testQrys);
?>
<select size='5' width='925' style='width: 925px' name='users' onchange='showUser(this.value)' multiple>

<?php while($test = mysql_fetch_array($testdbResults )) { ?>

<option class='h4' value='<?php print($test[9]); ?>'>
    <?php print($test[5]);echo" ( ";print($test[9]);echo" )"; ?>
</option>

        <?php } ?>
</select>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

and the get_user.php code is:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','airways');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM test WHERE m_email = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo "<input type='text' name='staff_no[]' value='".$row['m_staff_no']."'>";
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

now what i want is when i select one user in the select option it shows the staff no of that user but when i select multiple users it does not show the staff no of other users i select.

please help me with the change in code so i can get the staff no of users like (22344, 44333, 33344, 55443, 11125, 25263) in the text box

waiting for the kind and prompt responses.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check to see the value sent by the javascript. If you have a multiple selection then $q will not be an array but rather a string. If it's comma separated you should change your query to something like `WHERE m_email IN ([list of emails here])`.

Comment: i did it where m_email in ('".$q."') but nothing same it doesnt show all users staff no when i select more than one user name it shows only one....

Comment: What is the value of $q when you select multiple users?

Comment: its in the javascript   xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/get_user.php?q="+str,true); and i hope something will be done here or else i dont know

Comment: Ok, add this after `$q=$_GET["q"];`: `file_put_contents('log.txt', $q);`, run it with multiple users, open log.txt and post back what is inside it. Note that PHP will need write permission for this to work.

Comment: only one email is there because the value of <option> is the email i have selected 3 users but it is showing only one email in the text file. and even when u select the 1st, 3rd and 4th or watever it is showing only the 1st records value from the combobox. but i want to show the staff no in the text box through the get_user.php

Comment: this is the image what it is showing: http://oi43.tinypic.com/34e9ers.jpg
and this is the image how i want it to be look like:
http://oi39.tinypic.com/zo7qjk.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from `showUser(this.value)`. This returns only the first selected element's value. You need to cycle through all options and concatenate them together to make a string that you will be able to send as a parameter.

Change your javascript code to something along those lines. Note that you will need to change your PHP code in order to separate the emails, sanitize them and create a working `WHERE m_email IN ()` query.

You will need to add `id="users"` to your HTML code first.

```
var usersList = document.getElementById('users');
var emailString = '';

for (user_counter = 0; user_counter < usersList.options.length; user_counter++) {
    if (usersList.options[user_counter].selected) {
        emailString += usersList.options[user_counter].value;
    }
}
```

Then send `emailString` as the parameter to the PHP script. Test it again with log.txt in case you get an error.

Comment: would you please give me the full code with your code so i can test??? i have given my all codes up.. please...

Comment: Would you please help i tried but its not working please set the code and post here please as per the codes i have given above

Comment: I will not recode your whole application and do all the work for you. If that is what you want you are at the wrong place. I am willing to help you if you give me enough information. What exactly is not working? What did you try? It's possible I missed something and my code is incomplete. It's also possible you made a mistake while copying and adapting my answer. However I cannot know this if you don't tell me what is going on.

You should strive to understand what is happening and what the changes I am suggesting imply.

Comment: @Technoh He's learning. He's already making vast improvements on here. Give him a chance. Maybe a little more explanation into how to find/read his log files and maybe a some links to what you "want" him to understand mentioned in your answer could help?

Comment: @SpYk3HH would you please help me in this regard???? waiting for your kind response....

Comment: @usman610 as soon as i can i will. just notice this message while looking for an answer. I'm drenched in my own work right now.